# How to Easily Eliminate Unnecessary Fonts in My Website?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, devtools

I use Google PageSpeed Insights to inspect my website. The result is at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.datanumen.com%2F&tab=mobile

In "Preload key requests", there are many fonts to be pre-loaded. I ask at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/optimize-page-load-speed/#new-topic-0 and many replies that using 22 fonts in a website is not necessary, so I want to eliminate some unnecessary fonts.

Currently I figure out two methods to eliminate unnecessary fonts:

1. Try to remove a @font-face declaration in CSS file, then I think all elements using that font will use fallback font instead. Then I will check each webpage to see if there are any outstanding bad result in the visual effect. If not, then the removal will be permanent.
2. In each @font-face declaration in CSS file, try to find the element use it by using Chrome DevTools inspect tool. Then modify the style to any one(most likely the fallback style), then check if there are any outstanding bad result in the visual effect. If not, then I can remove that specific @font-face declaration.

I have tried method 2, but find it is very time-consuming. Even for one page, it will take many time to find the element using a specific @font-face declaration.

So, I just wonder if there is an easy way or tool that can help to eliminate unnecessary fonts used in a webpage or website?

Comment: Do you mean to say you use 22 web fonts  and want an easy way or tool that can help to eliminate unnecessary fonts used in a webpage or website!?

Comment: @Ad-1, Yes, the unnecessary fonts may be unused fonts, or fonts that can be eliminated without affect the visual effect a lot.

Comment: I am a bit confused here; if you have unused fonts then why do you even need to load them?

Comment: @Ad-1, The website is designed by another company. So we don't know which fonts are necessary and which are not. Also some fonts may only be used once and in unimportant places, so they may be eliminated and use fallback fonts instead. But since the website is not created by me, I don't know how to that. The main issue is that the web development company said this belongs to SEO and they don't do that.

Comment: Well, there is no separate method for this, but the easiest thing to do, would be to first go the stylesheet page on a browser and search for the font name using the 'Find in Page' tool, so that you can know where the fonts have been used.